# (python, matplotlib) how can I do differential in graph that isn't from equation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

I got data and showed it as a graph with matplotlib.
and I reduced noise and under is the pictures of them.

[image: before reducing noise]

[image: after reducing noise]

and now I want to know the gradient of each points,
so I tried to do differential in my graph.

but when I found about that, I just got information of how to do that when you have the equation of the graph.

maybe this one can be work(code under), but how can I got the value of f(x+h) and f(x-h)?

```
def numerical_diff(f, x):
h = 1e-4
return (f(x+h) - f(x-h)) / (2*h)
```

sorry for poor English and thank you for reading.
I'll wait for your answer. help me pls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

numpy `np.gradient` would work on the data array you use to plot the data. You also need to supply dx which is the change between your variables,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, 100)
dx = x[1] - x[0]
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x, np.gradient(y, dx))
plt.show()
```

Numerical derivatives are noisy  You could also consider spline fitting and taking [derivatives](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.7.0/reference/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.derivative.html)  of these for smoother plots,

```
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

spl = UnivariateSpline(x, y, k=4, s=0)
diffspl = spl.derivative()

plt.plot(x, spl(x), '--')
plt.plot(x, diffspl(x), '--')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are attempting to do numeric differential, this can be accomplished in many ways, but the most simple is to use the equation that you have written.

```
def numerical_dif(y_data: list) -> list:
    differential = []
    for i in range(len(y_data) - 1):
        differential.append(y_data[i+1]-y_data[i])
    return differential
```

This assumes equidistant data points but could be easily modified to take x-axis position as well. If you are using NumPy, then the simplest differential is numpy.diff()

If you are looking for more complex solution look here
[Univariate spline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.derivative.html)

Comment: this one is more easy to understand. thank you and I'll try with your way